# "Can't find disk drive" during Ubuntu Karmic server install

Tags: installation, 9.10, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Karmic server and before the partitioning step it tells me that it can't detect the disk drive, and asks me to give it a driver name from a huge list. The problem is that I don't know what driver to use or how to find it.

I have a Maverick desktop cd, and when I boot into that I am able to view the drive and see the unallocated space in GParted. Unfortunately there are some requirements on the system which prevent me from using anything but Karmic on it right now, so a newer version isn't an option.

Is there a way I can get Karmic on this other than using the karmic installer?

The hard drive is `ATA WDC WD1600BJKT-7`.

Here's the output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset
```

Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the SATA controller settings in the BIOS so that it was in AHCI mode and not in IDE mode. After that it booted and installed normally.

Answer (score 1):

Karmic has reached end of life and is no longer supported.  Use a supported release.

Comment: As I said, that's not an option, as much as I'd like it to be.